# composite foreign key not working

Tags: sql, oracle, composite-primary-key

i have a product table with a composite primary key and the composite primary key is working as excpected but whenever i try to use this composite primary key as a foreign key in another table , it dosent work

primary table product:

```
create table product
(
product_id number(4) , 
sub_product_id number(3) , 
category_id references category, 
product_name varchar2(40), 
product_brand varchar2(30), 
price varchar2(15) , 
image_url varchar2(200) , 
color varchar2(30) , 
intmemory varchar2(30) ,
extmemory varchar2(30) , 
primary key(product_id,sub_product_id)
)
```

foreign key table cart :

```
create table cart
(
userid references register1 ,
product_id, 
sub_product_id, 
quantity number(3) , 
delivery_time varchar2(100) ,
foreign key(product_id ,sub_product_id) references product(product_id    ,sub_product_id)
)
```

primary table is working fine but foreign keys are not working , they dont give error when i insert same `(product_id , sub_product_id)`

All I want is that the cart table dosen't have multiply entries of the same `product_id, sub_product_id`

Comment: A foreign key is not a unique key!

Comment: Please post sample insert statements.

Comment: `insert into cart(userid,product_id,sub_product_id,quantity,delivery_time) values('session',8881,1,1,'4 days')` ... so how can i use a foreign composite key ?

Comment: @amolsingh if 8881,1 combination of id's will present in product table then cart table will accept those values for more then one time also.

Comment: @Tarun ...so what can i do in this case ??

Comment: Hi your two table structures are fine make different users will buy same in this scenario two entry's of same product and sub-product id's will happen. So please mention your problem exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jens mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933623/composite-foreign-key-not-working#comment51778723_31933623), a foreign key is not the same as a unique key. You can create a unique key simply:

```
ALTER TABLE cart
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
UNIQUE (product_id , sub_product_id);
```

Comment: Yes i can do that , but will this key refer to the product table ??

Comment: You can create in on whichever one you want, or both even. Doesn't make sense to me to have it on the cart table because it will stop 2 different people from buying the same item which is silly. You have to decide what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Ohhh i got your point .... That's okay ...i guess i don't need foreign key on cart table